# Admob always in button, no matter device (ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, tabbar

I have a problem with my `admob`. I want it to "stick" just above the `tabbar` in my app, but if i change from iphone 5 to iphone 4, the `admob` gets behind the `tabbar`, or gets below it(out of sight).

Heres the iPhone 5
[image: Heres the iphone 5]

Heres the iphone 4 - as you can see, the admob gets below the tabbar.
[image: Heres the iphone 4]

How can this be done/fixed ? so the admob follows the tabbar, no matter the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the issue of constraints.Since iPhone 4 screen is smaller than iPhone 5, admob control went down to the tabbar control.To fix this issue, Try to add Bottom constraint to Admob.